Characterization of Minimal Dominating Set in the Complement of a Graph
Let $G$ be a connected simple graph, and let $ \overline{G}$ denote the complement of $G$.
Suppose $X$ is a minimal dominating set in $\overline{G}$.
What is the characterization of the set $X$ in terms of the original graph $G$?
I am looking for a clear understanding of how the structure of $G$ influences the minimal dominating set $X$ in $\overline{G}$. Any insights, theorems, or references would be helpful.

The required reformulation is straightforward. Let $V$ be the set of vertices of $G$. A subset $D$ of $V$ is dominating of $\overline{G}$ iff each vertex $v\in V\setminus D$ is nonadjacent so some vertex $u\in D$. Also we can speak about minimal subsets $D$ of $V$ having this property. I searched a bit
for related insights, theorems, and references in the Wikipedia article,
"Chromatic Graph Theory" by Gary Chartrand and Ping Zhang, and my old answers, but found nothing nontrivial. So I guess that the related results are mainly straightforward reformulations. For instance, we can reformulate the Ore theorem: if $S$ is a minimal dominating set of a graph $G$ without isolated vertices, then $V\setminus S$ is a dominating set of $G$.
